# xml file not showing correct in iframe

Tags: xml, iframe

I am using iframe src to load external xml file into html page in firefox, but it sometimes shows up correctly as the xml raw code, but sometimes it seems to digest it as html.

I am not sure what caused this.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get some ideas of how to structure your question so other users of this site can provide good answers.  In particular, try to provide enough details so that others can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use firebug to check what the Content-Type of the server response is. (You will find that in the network tab, then have a look at the specific request's details).

Most probably you will have mixed content types here, which Firefox uses to determine what you are loading.

Other things that Firefox might use, is the file extension, if there is any.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to see the network tab and see the response content-type is actually text/xml and other information is also quite the same compared to the situation it shows correctly. Moreover, when I repeat the process, sometimes it shows raw xml, sometimes it shows the html code.